# How to compare RPM's between x2 different Jenkins VMs?

Tags: rpm

I installed two jenkins VMs and I would like to compare the RPMS between the two VMS.

Can this be done from putty? Or is there a way to export the results to an output file?

Comment: One way to compare would be to check the two rpms md5 checksum. One other way is to compare two Jenkins versions. It is not clear what you are trying to compare.

Comment: Trying to compare the versions of RPMs installed on x2 different jenkins machines. One should be running the latest versions of RPM while the other should be running a specified version. One the console output I can see a specified version for one VM (which is correct) and the other jut says 'latest version' I need to know which verison it is and compare it against the other VM. If that makes any sense?

Comment: Why is your question tagged as related to the OpenVMS family of operating systems (`vms`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rpm -q` queries and you can get a specific format with `--queryformat`. To compare two versions you're on your own.